# Correct way of thinking approach in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, coding-style

Today I was just doing some exercise of recursion. Although i can judge problems whether it is related to recursion or not and finally made them solved. But it usually takes me time. Because i have to think recursively.

So over here i am explaining how do i solve recursive problems

```
public class FabonicciNumberFinder {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number=6;
    //System.out.println(findLastFabNumber(number-2,1,1));


    System.out.println(findFabNumber(number));
}
private static int findFabNumber(int number) {
    if(number <=1)
        return number;

    return findFabNumber(number-1) + findFabNumber(number-2);
}
//1 1 2 3 5 8

private static int findLastFabNumber(int number,int firstNumber, int lastNumber) {
    if(number == 0)
        return lastNumber;

    return findLastFabNumber(number-1, lastNumber, firstNumber+lastNumber);
}
```

}

If you look at above two solutions of finding fabonacci number at certain position. There are two ways given above. One is findFabNumber() and other one is findLastFabNumber(). findLastFabNumber() is coded by me and other one is normally available to online.
Here was my thought process.

In Fibonacci series i have to maintain two number. In first call two one's will get passed but when recursive method gets called number must be update. because next number would be sum of last two number. But i have to find Fibonacci number at certain position. So i have to pass a position counter in recursive method call as well and that would get decremented. After that i think recursively last call when counter that is decrementing becomes 0. That moment i have to return lastNumber. Hence it is coded. But when i saw solution online. This is given as in another way(findFabNumber()). It has two recursive calls. But it is very readable as per concept. Because as per concept sum of last two number will be your next number. so i just have passed n and directly coded

```
  return findFabNumber(number-1) + findFabNumber(number-2)
```

I didn't have to think recursively except base condition. Here are two recursive calls. Similarly If we want to find number of subsets of array. We can achieve by just having two recursive method calls. We do not to think deeply in recursive manner.  I have seen people thinking in tree structure from top to bottom on paper but i couldn't think tree structure for all recursive problems.  So i have to think in my way if it is recursive problems.

What is your thought process to solve recursion problems like me or any other. Do you think recursively as well.

It might be silly question but important to me. Because if way of thinking of doing things is proper then things would be easy for us. I usually think so.

Comment: Use `Dynamic Programming` for overlapping sub-problems.

Comment: This is not a coding question, it might fit just as well in mathematics or philosophy. So off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `findLastFabNumber` uses a recursive function call, but it does not solve the fibonacci problem recursively. Your solution is the iterative solution to the problem "disguised" in a recursive method call.

One way to see that is that your findLastFabNumber requires additional arguments, and if those are not the starting condition for fibonacci, your function will not compute the n-th fibonacci number.

A true recursive solution to a problem solves exactly the same problem on a smaller scale. So the correct way of thinking in recursion is to try to solve a problem by solving the exact same problem on a "smaller" scale, and then compute the difference to the next higher scale.

> Here was my thought process. In Fibonacci series i have to maintain two number...

This is the problem. You have to maintain 2 numbers only in the iterative solution to Fibonacci, but in the abstract description of the Fibonacci problem, you do not need to maintain two numbers. You thought of the iterative solution first, not of the abstract problem.

Also, btw. while your solution is creative, it is worse than the classical iterative solution to Fibonacci using a plain loop (in terms of readability, and of stack usage in languages like Java).